# Script to only show timestamp when a specific column is changed?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I want to take an existing script from a Google Spreadsheets and change it so it only updates the last column when I make a change to a specific column in the last row. I can't get it to only key off of the one column, it continues to change the last column whenever I make any change to the sheet. Any ideas?

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
    var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet(),getcolumn=("s");

  // note: actRng = the cell being updated
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var cindex = actRng.getColumnIndex();

  var dateCol = sheet.getLastColumn();  
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(index,dateCol);
   var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "MM-dd-yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss' _'");

  lastCell.setValue("'" + date);
}
```

Comment: So you only want it to edit the **last** column if you edit the **last** row?

Comment: Does your script even compile without errors? The line `event.source.getActiveSheet(),getcolumn=("s")` looks strange. When that's fixed, you're not checking `index`or `cindex` to see if the edit event occured in the desired column.

Answer (score 2):

This script checks if column `B` is updated, then updates the last column in that row with a timestamp:

```
function onEdit(event) { 
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();

  // note: actRng = the cell being updated
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var cindex = actRng.getColumnIndex();

  if (cindex == 2) { // 1 == Column A, 2 == Column B, 3 == Column C, etc.
   var dateCol = sheet.getLastColumn();  
   var lastCell = sheet.getRange(index,dateCol);
   var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "MM-dd-yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss' _'");
   lastCell.setValue("'" + date);
  }
}
```

Note that the term "last column" will mean that, when starting with an empty spreadsheet, the value you enter in e.g. column `B` will be overwritten with the timestamp, since column `B` will be the "last column".

I set up [an example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1awxN8DgBYXlNu4Had6dgGdSiUeKoggQiF5_RsEX77Q0/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate. Feel free to copy it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried the script you offered but it didnt quite  provide the needed result.  I'm very new to scripts so I likely didn't communicate the ask very well.  In short, I have a spreadsheet with 24 columns.  New rows are added daily with detail added along each cell of the row from columns A thru W.  I want column X to be populated with a day/time time stamp that reflects the day/time when any value was added or changed for column S.  Again, thank you for your feedback